# How can access to a external file using loadScript?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, cli

I'm using loadScript in ethereum console to load a external js file:

> loadScript('teste.js');

```
// teste.js

function fx() {
return 12;
}
```

However when I run it in ethereum console it always returns false:
(teste.js is located in a folder 'src' in the datadir - admin.datadir)

> loadScript('src/teste.js')
>   false

Why I do have this behaviour? Should return 12?
I also tried placing the .js in various reasonable locations, but the ouput of loadScript() is always false...

I hope someone could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value `false` means that [your file in that relative path cannot be found](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#loadscript). First try running the file from within the same folder from which you started your geth.

Be reminded that this function will not print the return value to the console like that, you need some `console.log`. You could write an output with the following file that you store as `test.js`:

```
console.log('Hello world');
console.log('You have ' + web3.eth.accounts.length + ' accounts here.');
```

and then run it from within the geth console via `loadScript('test.js')`:

```
> loadScript('parse.js')
Hello world
You have 1 accounts here.
true
```